# Android Bluetooth Api support for Pan profile?

Tags: android, api, bluetooth

I am trying to establish tcp/ip connection over bluetooth,currently android bluetooth api  provides support only for headset,a2dp and health device profiles,but I need PAN profile on manually assigned Ip address,I am not sure but I read somewhere even if you connect your phone to laptop using pan profile the ip address is automatically assigned,and you need to root your phone to manually assign them.Is it possible?

Is it possible to do easily over other platforms like ios or windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pan profile in Android, however It is not officially supported. Take a look at the Android Internal API.